# MySQL - таблица становится неизменяемой после добавления поля с типом ENUM

Tags: mysql, enum

Через `Phpmyadmin` добавил в структуру таблицы с довольно большим количеством элементов новое поле с типом `ENUM`. 4 не особо длинных значения. Также выставил одно из них как значение по-умолчанию.

Появилось две проблемы:

1. `Phpmyadmin` больше не отображает структуру этой таблицы в соотв. вкладке. Будто бы игнорирует клик на вкладку, но не зависает при этом.
2. Попытки внести изменения в поля этой таблицы безуспешны. Ошибок нет, но значения не меняются.

С таблицей раньше все было хорошо, данные устанавливались и получались быстро. Дело именно в `ENUM` т.к. убирая его через `DROP COLUMN` я получаю рабочую таблицу.

Я думал `ENUM` - экономичный тип и не особо сильно нагружает БД?

Comment: Проблема скорее всего в phpmyadmin, посмотрите его логи или Проверьте работу бд другой тулзой

Comment: А есть хорошая замена ENUM-ам

Answer (score 1):

Использовать ENUM в MySQL крайне не рекомендую. Лучше данные поля хранить, как целые числа. Для хранения значений можно создать отдельную страницу.
Также добавление новых значений в ENUM приведет к alter table.